# !(ReferenceEquals()) vs != in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, inequality

Unless a class specifically overrides the behavior defined for Object, [ReferenceEquals and == do the same thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)... compare references.

In property setters, I have commonly used the pattern

```
private MyType myProperty;

public MyType MyProperty
{
    set
    {
        if (myProperty != value)
        {
            myProperty = value;
            // Do stuff like NotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }
}
```

However, in code generated by Entity Framework, the `if` statement is replaced by

```
    if (!ReferenceEquals(myProperty, value))
```

Using ReferenceEquals is more explicit (as I guess not all C# programmers know that == does the same thing if not overridden).

Is there any difference that's escaping me between the two if-variants?  Are they perhaps accounting for the possibility that POCO designers may have overridden `==`?

In short, if I have not overridden `==`, am I save using != instead of `ReferenceEquals()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the different semantics:

- `ReferenceEquals()` must be used if you mean that the objects are exactly the same (identity check).
- `object.Equals()` shall be used if you mean the objects have the same value (equality check)
- `==()` shall only be used for immutable types. Then use it to test for equality.

Of course the inversed counterparts are meant accordingly.

[Here is a summary](http://www.color-of-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=62:c-equality-vs-identity&catid=45:programming&Itemid=68)

Comment: Why the Golden Rule `If you want to know if two objects refer to the same instance USE ONLY ReferenceEquals`?  MSDN states `For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx  Not challenging the Golden Rule, just want to understand it.

Comment: Just because it always works. The == might be wrongly implemented which makes it potentially problematic. It saved my life when I decided to make my objects immutable in a project, where == is overriden for equality not identity. So I always use ReferenceEquals if objects, not values must be compared.

Answer (score -3):

== should test to see if the reference points to the same location whereas ReferenceEquals tests to see if they contain the same data

Comment: I think this should be the exact opposite, tbh.

Comment: Hmm...Well after some quick tests == and ReferenceEquals produce the same results but I suppose you're right. Oh well -points for me :)

Comment: This is because unless overridden the == operator usually performs a reference equality check.

When overridden however, it may or may not use this. Therefore the == operator should not be used if you want to check for reference equality on immutable types.